# How do i get rid of `Definition for rule 'simple-import-sort/imports' was not found`?

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslintrc

I inherited a project and I don't want this plugin or rule anymore.
I've removed all instances of `simple-import-sort` from package.json and eslint.rc.
I can't find any mentions of this anywhere...

Yet when i run my server, this error comes up.

I don't understand what could be causing this error to come up, if I have no explicit plugins or rules for `simple-import-sort`

My eslintrc is pasted below:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const foldersUnderSrc = fs
    .readdirSync('src', { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter((dirent) => dirent.isDirectory())
    .map((dirent) => dirent.name)

module.exports = {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser', // Specifies the ESLint parser
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:react/recommended',
        'plugin:jsx-a11y/strict',
    ],
    env: {
        browser: true,
        jasmine: true,
        jest: true,
    },
    plugins: ['react', 'react-hooks', 'jsx-a11y'],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2018, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
        sourceType: 'module', // Allows for the use of imports
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true, // Allows for the parsing of JSX
        },
    },
    rules: {
        // Place to specify ESLint rules. Can be used to overwrite rules specified from the extended configs
        // e.g. "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/ban-types': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/camelcase': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 0,
        'no-async-promise-executor': 0,
        'no-console': 0,
        'no-irregular-whitespace': 0,
        'react/jsx-key': 0,
        'no-restricted-imports': [
            2,
            {
                paths: [
                    {
                        name: 'lodash',
                        message:
                            "Do not import from `lodash` directly, as we don't support tree-shaking for it. Instead, import the function you're trying to use, e.g. `import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'`",
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
        'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 1,
        'react/jsx-sort-default-props': [
            'warn',
            {
                ignoreCase: false,
            },
        ],
        'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 1,
        'react/prop-types': 0,
        'react/display-name': 0,
        'react/no-unescaped-entities': 0,
        'jsx-a11y/no-autofocus': 0,
        'jsx-a11y/media-has-caption': 0,
        '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function': 0,
        'react/jsx-uses-react': 0,
        'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 0
    },
    settings: {
        react: {
            pragma: 'React',
            version: 'detect', // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
        },
    },
    globals: {
        global: 'readonly',
        Atomics: 'readonly',
        process: true,
        SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
        Promise: 'readonly',
        Buffer: 'readonly',
        WeakSet: 'readonly',
        setImmediate: 'readonly',
        setInterval: 'readonly',
        setTimeout: 'readonly',
        shallow: 'readonly',
        page: 'readonly',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error:
I added the following into .eslintrc:

- "simple-import-sort"
- "simple-import-sort/imports": "off",
- "simple-import-sort/exports": "off,

as per below code and now I no longer have those errors. But I don't know why that fixed it.

```
"plugins": ["prettier", "react", "react-hooks", "simple-import-sort", "react-native"],
"rules": {
   "simple-import-sort/imports": "off",
   "simple-import-sort/exports": "off,
}
```

Comment: Because you turned off rules?